# Value entered in a function changed by the default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I created this function:

```
def bs_obj(url, lan="html.parser"):
    try:
        html = urlopen(url)
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, lan)
        print(lan)
        return bsObj
    except HTTPError as e:
        print(e)
```

Now, if I call the function with the next code: `object = bs_obj(html, "lxml")`, the console prints `html.parser`. Same goes if the code is `object = bs_obj(html, lan="lxml")`. What's going on?

EDIT: (SOLVED) I'm ashamed. I was calling `bs_obj(html)` some lines before the codeline I used as example.

Comment: *What's going on here?* isn't a title that will help other users having a similar problem. Please kindly edit

Comment: That about what the value of `lan` is at `print(lan)`... Maybe you meant to print `bsObj` or not print `lan` at all?

Comment: Sorry, changing the title right away!

Comment: Can you show the calling code?

Comment: @cricket_007 I placed that print just to show that the function is using the default `lan` value.

Comment: @jamesdlin added some examples there.

Comment: It shouldn't print `html.parser` with `bs_obj(html, lan="lxml")`

Comment: By the way, this is not a minimal example. BeautifulSoup nor urllib are needed to show this behavior

Comment: @cricket_007 could it be that I'm using pycharm?

Comment: I doubt it. Are you sure you are editing the correct file. I cannot reproduce this behavior you describe and I am also using PyCharm

Comment: @cricket_007 there it is! I was importinng bs_obj from an older version file. Thanks!

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope, it's not an older version. I'm importing the right file. My bad :/

Comment: Please provide a short, complete example. Shorter, in that you probably don't need `urllib` or `BeautifulSoup` to demonstrate the problem. Complete, in that we need to see a whole program that we can run. See [mcve] for more information about sample programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are running the wrong file. For reference.

```
def bs_obj(lan="html.parser"):
    print(lan)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bs_obj()
    bs_obj("lxml")
    bs_obj(lan='html5.parser')
```

Correctly outputs

```
html.parser
lxml
html5.parser
```